# Tasty xml *and* html generation?

Tags: haskell, automated-tests

I would like to use both `tasty-ant-xml` and `tasty-html` simultaneously. However,

```
defaultMainWithIngredients (antXMLRunner:htmlRunner:defaultIngredients)
```

Doing this and supplying both `--html` and `--xml` options at the command line seems to only use the xml output. Is there a way I can get both (*and* ideally also output to the console as usual) without running the test suite multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [composeReporters](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-1.3.1/docs/Test-Tasty-Ingredients.html). I haven't tried it, but something like this should work:

```
defaultMainWithIngredients
  (( antXMLRunner `composeReporters` 
     htmlRunner `composeReporters`
     consoleTestReporter
   ) : defaultIngredients)
```

(and if it doesn't, please open an issue)